# C++ map::erase behaviour

Tags: c++, class, reference, containers

I wish to take a reference to an object out of one C++ `std::map` and put it in another - eg to move an object from a low to a high priority tree.

If I `erase` the object from one tree, do I invalidate it completely? What if I have it in both trees at once and then `erase` (ie the object is referenced twice).

The documentation implies that the object will be invalidated in either case, but it's not 100% clear IMHO.

**update** here's an example - but looks to me that this just isn't going to work - using references at least - I'll have to use some form of pointer...

```
PartialPage oldPage = hTree->oldestPage();
lTree->insertOldPage(oldPage);
hTree->erase(oldPage);
```

NB `oldestPage()` returns a reference to a `PartialPage`

Comment: You could use `std::shared_ptr` if the element could be in the 2 maps at the same time, if not use `std::unique_ptr` to passed from one to the other. The procedure would be, get the `elem` eg: with `find` function, moved to the other map (the ptr would be empty at this point), erase the `elem`.

Comment: What are you actually storing in your map - an object, or a pointer?

Comment: An object - looks like I am on a hiding to nothing though :(

Comment: Can you come up with a simple code example to clarify what objects you actually store in your map?

Comment: I have added some code now, but I think it's pretty clear I cannot do this with references

Comment: Unlike `std::list`, the other containers don't have "splice" operations that can exchange nodes across different containers. Shame, it would be nice if those existed.

Comment: Very difficult to answer this when the only code shown is a random arbitrary snippet using types where we have no idea what those types do

Comment: If `oldestPage` indeed returns a reference, then this "code" makes a copy of the returned `PartialPage`, inserts the copy in the alternate container, then erases the original. Could you do this better with move-semantics? Probably, but I concur with NetVipC on this.

Answer (score 1):

Containers own the elements within them, by virtue of storing their own copies. Your object is *not* in "both containers" at any time.

If you wish to introduced shared-resource semantics, you will have to store `std::shared_ptr<PartialPage>`s in your maps.